# fetch_array with prepared statement? PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason I cannot get this to work for the life of me, I am new to prepared statements!

```
    $q = $dbc -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && logcount = ''");
    $q -> bind_param ('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
    $row = $q -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $q -> execute();
    $q -> store_result();
        if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {
            $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET logcount = '0' WHERE email = ?");
            $q -> bind_param('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
            $q -> execute();
            echo 'Congratulations ' . $row['username'] . ' your account is now active!';
        }
```

Any ideas why $row['username'] will not print? It returns a :
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Thanks.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php  browse down to Example 1.  There is no fetch_array() method.  you need to "bind result"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `fetch_array` in this case.

If you want to use get the data from the query, you need to use [`bind_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [`fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) after calling [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call  `$q -> execute();` prior to fetching result.

Comment: I did that, and edited my question, it throws the same error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it wrong, when you call execute it returns a result object, which is what you call your fetch methods on:

```
$q = $dbc->prepare ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? && logcount = ''");
$q->bind_param ('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));

//Updated Here
$result = $q -> execute();

if ($result->num_rows == 1)
{
    $assocData = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //Do other stuff
}
```