# Fetch_array alternative for PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, fetch

## UPDATE

```
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
SELECT u.id,    u.fname,    u.lname,    u.mname,  u.type, u.email, u.salt,
       u.pass,  u.salt,     u.approved, u.ban,      u2.status
FROM `users` AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `log` AS u2
        ON u2.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.email = ? LIMIT 1") or die($this->db->error);

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']) or die($stmt->error);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
            die($this->ajax->respond(7));
        }
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Trying to fetch array but getting following error for last line

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object
```

Can't get it work. Please help

Comment: What DB interface is that? MySQLi?

Comment: what is $result? tried echoing it?

Comment: not sure about the answer but try to use $stmt instead of $result...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi tried no success

Comment: @epic_syntax ok if $result is a boolean `1`, why would `$result->anythingatall` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

PDO gives this beautiful function for that purpose.

Edit: i thought it was PDO interface. Why you aren't using pdo? I find it way comfortable than mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_stmt::execute` does not return the result, only `true` or `false`. You fetch the result from the `mysqli_stmt` object itself. Please carefully read the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php.

Comment: Please take a look at Robert Pitts answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679600/fetch-array-with-prepared-statement-php-mysql

Comment: Well, look at the manual. `mysqli_stmt::execute` does not return an object.

Answer (score 0):

With [`get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) you can get a resultset from the executed statement:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
```

Comment: Please take a look on updated question: modified code by your suggestion. Nothing has changed

Comment: What if I want to get the `n`th result? MySQLi is f'ed up.